# Arabic: Convert notmal Arabic text to Presentation Forms-B

Tags: string, unicode, arabic, unicode-string, arabic-support

**Background**

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152091/the-structure-of-arabic-letters-in-unicode) answer:

> Arabic is a script with cursive joining; the shape of the letters changes depending on whether they occur initially, medially, or finally within a word. Sometimes you may want to display these contextual forms in isolation, for example to simply show what they look like.
>
> The recommended way to go about this is by using special join-causing characters for the letters to connect to. One of these is the tatweel (also called kashida), which is essentially a short line segment with “glue” at each end. So if you surround the letter م with a tatweel character on both sides, the text renderer automatically selects its medial form as if it occured in the middle of a word (ـمـ). The underlying character code of the م doesn’t change, only its visible glyph.
>
> However, for historical reasons Unicode also contains a large set of so-called presentation forms for Arabic. These represent those same contextual letter shapes, but as separate character codes that do not change depending on their surroundings; putting the “isolated” presentation form of م between two tatweels does not affect its appearance, for instance: ـﻡـ

**Situation**

I have to display string on a very foolish device, that doesn't have any ability of smart rendering characters by their context. The device can only get an array of unicode numbers [encoded as utf8] and display glyphs for every number.

So, if I want to display arabic text, I have to use the "Presentation Forms" codes to export the string.

How can I convert the normal string to Presentation Forms string?

I would love to get a solution in any language, especially Python, C# or JS.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think there's anything out of the box for this. You'll have to do it yourself by analyzing the surrounding characters and deciding on which shape to use.  Here's [an example](https://github.com/Accorpa/Arabic-Converter-From-and-To-Arabic-Presentation-Forms-B) I found. It's in Objective C (not C#). And here's [another one](https://github.com/NaurozAhmad/Arabic-Urdu-Converter-From-and-To-Presentation-Forms-B) in JavaScript. Shouldn't be too difficult to follow one of them and write your version in C#.

Comment: Thenks! I will use it.